# Cannot find module @angular/common/http Ionic 3 app

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3, ngx-translate

I have done the `Ionic 3` app's internationalization using `ngx-translate`.It gave me below error.

I have done that using [**official doc here**](https://ionicframework.com/docs/developer-resources/ng2-translate/).

> Cannot find module '@angular/common/http'

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was `@angular/common/http` is only available in `angular 4.3+`.But on `Ionic 3` we're using `Angular 4.1.3`.

So this is the solution:

I have **removed** `@ngx-translate/http-loader`

> npm uninstall @ngx-translate/http-loader --save

And **add** an older version of it:

> npm i @ngx-translate/http-loader@0.1.0 --save

You can read more about it [**on Git**](https://github.com/ngx-translate/http-loader/issues/21)

Answer (score 0):

`HttpClient` was introduced in [Angular 4.3.0](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#430-2017-07-14), you are using 4.1.3.

In the Angular version you are using you can inject `Http` (requires `HttpModule` in `imports: [...]` of `AppModule`), but it has different features and a different API.