# Why is my Ionic Pro build failing in but my local build is fine?

Tags: ionic2

I have an Ionic 3 app which I've been developing and I need to move to Ionic Pro and it has not been easy. I use npm-check-updates from time to time but I think that has gotten me in trouble with Ionic. When I first pushed my app to Ionic Pro, the build failed but I googled it and I realized that my Angular version was ahead of Ionic and I had to down-version my app from Angular 4.4.3 to 4.1.3 (thanks to [Cannot find module @angular/common/http Ionic 3 app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46077427/cannot-find-module-angular-common-http-ionic-3-app)) and rewrite it to work. Fine. But now I am getting another error, and I assume that it is something like this, but I cannot figure it out. I posted something to the Ionic Forum but did not get a response. The error I am getting is below. Any help would be appreciated. I will ask "mother may I" before I update my Ionic app, but I need to know what to roll back to keep building my program. Thanks!

> [11:08:39] Error: ./~/firebase/utils/promise.js Module not found:
>   Error: Can’t resolve ‘promise-polyfill’ in
>   ’/usr/src/app/node_modules/firebase/utils’ resolve ‘promise-polyfill’
>   in ’/usr/src/app/node_modules/firebase/utils’ Parsed request is a
>   module using description file:
>   /usr/src/app/node_modules/firebase/package.json (relative path:
>   ./utils) Field ‘browser’ doesn’t contain a valid alias configuration
>   after using description file:
>   /usr/src/app/node_modules/firebase/package.json (relative path:
>   ./utils) resolve as module looking for modules in
>   /usr/src/app/node_modules using description file:
>   /usr/src/app/package.json (relative path: ./node_modules) Field
>   ‘browser’ doesn’t contain a valid alias configuration after using
>   description file: /usr/src/app/package.json (relative path:
>   ./node_modules) using description file: /usr/src/app/package.json
>   (relative path: ./node_modules/promise-polyfill) as directory
>   /usr/src/app/node_modules/promise-polyfill doesn’t exist no extension
>   Field ‘browser’ doesn’t contain a valid alias configuration
>   /usr/src/app/node_modules/promise-polyfill doesn’t exist .ts Field
>   ‘browser’ doesn’t contain a valid alias configuration
>   /usr/src/app/node_modules/promise-polyfill.ts doesn’t exist .js Field
>   ‘browser’ doesn’t contain a valid alias configuration
>   /usr/src/app/node_modules/promise-polyfill.js doesn’t exist .json
>   Field ’browser’ doesn’t contain a valid alias configuration
>   /usr/src/app/node_modules/promise-polyfill.json doesn’t exist
>   [/usr/src/app/node_modules/promise-polyfill]
>   [/usr/src/app/node_modules/promise-polyfill]
>   [/usr/src/app/node_modules/promise-polyfill.ts]
>   [/usr/src/app/node_modules/promise-polyfill.js]
>   [/usr/src/app/node_modules/promise-polyfill.json] @
>   ./~/firebase/utils/promise.js 14:76-103 @
>   ./~/firebase/app/firebase_app.js @ ./~/firebase/app.js @
>   ./src/providers/user.service.ts @ ./src/app/app.module.ts @
>   ./src/app/main.ts Error: ./~/firebase/utils/promise.js Module not
>   found: Error: Can’t resolve ‘promise-polyfill’ in
>   '/usr/src/app/node_modules/firebase/utils’ resolve ‘promise-polyfill’
>   in '/usr/src/app/node_modules/firebase/utils’ Parsed request is a
>   module using description file:
>   /usr/src/app/node_modules/firebase/package.json (relative path:
>   ./utils) Field ‘browser’ doesn’t contain a valid alias configuration
>   after using description file:
>   /usr/src/app/node_modules/firebase/package.json (relative path:
>   ./utils) resolve as module looking for modules in
>   /usr/src/app/node_modules using description file:
>   /usr/src/app/package.json (relative path: ./node_modules) Field
>   ‘browser’ doesn’t contain a valid alias configuration after using
>   description file: /usr/src/app/package.json (relative path:
>   ./node_modules) using description file: /usr/src/app/package.json
>   (relative path: ./node_modules/promise-polyfill) as directory
>   /usr/src/app/node_modules/promise-polyfill doesn’t exist no extension
>   Field ‘browser’ doesn’t contain a valid alias configuration
>   /usr/src/app/node_modules/promise-polyfill doesn’t exist .ts Field
>   ‘browser’ doesn’t contain a valid alias configuration
>   /usr/src/app/node_modules/promise-polyfill.ts doesn’t exist .js Field
>   ‘browser’ doesn’t contain a valid alias configuration
>   /usr/src/app/node_modules/promise-polyfill.js doesn’t exist .json
>   Field ‘browser’ doesn’t contain a valid alias configuration
>   /usr/src/app/node_modules/promise-polyfill.json doesn’t exist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The magic is going to github.com/ionic-team/ionic/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md and making sure you have the latest version of the ionic modules and the latest version of Angular they support.

For today, that means running

npm install -g ionic@latest

npm install @ionic/app-scripts@2.1.4 --save-dev

npm install ionic-angular@3.6.1 --save